# How do I send an SMS via the Twilio API (using HTTP POST in server-side javascript ) that includes accent characters (for instance ö)?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm trying to send an SMS via Twilio's API using an HTTP POST request that is called via server-side javascript in salesforce marketing cloud.

I can successfully send an SMS, the only problem is that accent characters (for instance ö, ü, à, è) are being omitted. So for instance if I send an SMS that should say "Dein persönlicher Rabatt", when I received the SMS, it says "Dein persnlicher Rabatt".

Here is my server-side javascript code:

```
`<script type="text/javascript" runat="server">
Platform.Load("core", "1");

var accountSid = [accountSid];
var authToken  = [authToken];

var auth = Base64Encode(accountSid + ":" + authToken);

var phoneDE = DataExtension.Init("[Data Extension external key]");
var numbers = phoneDE.Rows.Retrieve();
var end = numbers.length;

for (var i=0; i<end; i++) {

var config = {
endpoint: "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/[accountSid]/Messages.json",
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
payload : "From=[phone]&To=" + numbers[i]["Phone"] + "&Body=Your cöntract is expiring    today, you can sign it here: " + numbers[i]["URL"]
};

Write("Payload" + i + ": " + config.payload + " ");

try {
var httpResult = HTTP.Post(
  config.endpoint,
  config.contentType,
  config.payload,
  ["Authorization"],
  ["Basic " + auth]
);
  
var result = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(httpResult.response);
Write(httpResult.StatusCode);
Write("result" + result);
} catch(error) {
Write("Error: " + Stringify(error));
}

}

</script>`
```

What do I need to do to ensure that my SMS includes the accent characters and that they are not omitted?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your answer Swimburger. I didn't get a chance to try it as I found another solution. However I do appreciate your feedback, your solution was the next approach I was going to try.

My solution was to modify the contentType of the POST request to include UTF-8 as the character set:

contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"

Comment: I'm glad you were able to solve it! Thank you for sharing your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't have access to a Salesforce environment to try out your code, but here's a modified version of your code using node.js.

```js
var accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
var authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;

var auth = Buffer.from(`${accountSid}:${authToken}`).toString('base64');

var body = new URLSearchParams();
body.append("From", "+12345678901");
body.append("To", "+12345678901");
body.append("Body", "ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿĀāĂăĄą");

const request = new Request(
    `https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/${accountSid}/Messages.json`,
    {
        method: 'POST',
        body: body.toString(),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization': `Basic ${auth}`
        }
    }
);

fetch(request)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(jsonBody => console.log(jsonBody))
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

You need to configure the Twilio Account SID and Auth Token as [env variables](https://www.twilio.com/blog/working-with-environment-variables-in-node-js-html).
After that, running this script sends an SMS and the SMS contains all the characters.

---

I'm not sure if you are able to use these node.js APIs, but if you don't, this proves that the issue is caused by Salesforce's Server Side JavaScript APIs.
`HTTP.Post` probably removes the `ö` character.
If you do have access to node.js/npm packages, you could also use [the Twilio helper library for Node.js](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node).